# Capistrano/Git not recognising checkout -B flag unless logged in via ssh

Tags: wordpress, git, ssh, dreamhost

I'm trying to use capistrano to deploy a wordpress site to my account on dreamhost.

For the most part capistrano seems to be working. Here's the output from cap dev git:check

```
$ cap dev git:check
 INFO [1cd5c6b7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/ on theparisstilton.com
DEBUG [1cd5c6b7] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/
 INFO [1cd5c6b7] Finished in 1.895 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [4ede30ed] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh on theparisstilton.com
DEBUG [4ede30ed] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh
 INFO [4ede30ed] Finished in 0.317 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [8d47d9d7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/ on theparisstilton.com
DEBUG [8d47d9d7] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/
 INFO [8d47d9d7] Finished in 1.668 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [1aacdb9a] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh on theparisstilton.com
DEBUG [1aacdb9a] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh
 INFO [1aacdb9a] Finished in 0.266 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [bd5cfd74] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:sentur/partisstilton.git on theparisstilton.com
DEBUG [bd5cfd74] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:sentur/partisstilton.git )
DEBUG [bd5cfd74]    5cadb90b1a5d4bbe59c2eb8e3f3e108f49b98fd0    HEAD
DEBUG [bd5cfd74]    9451025272b2a594ffc2af259bfce50c66ff15fc    refs/heads/dev
DEBUG [bd5cfd74]    5cadb90b1a5d4bbe59c2eb8e3f3e108f49b98fd0    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [bd5cfd74] Finished in 2.722 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [baacc1b3] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:sentur/partisstilton.git on theparisstilton.com
DEBUG [baacc1b3] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:sentur/partisstilton.git )
DEBUG [baacc1b3]    5cadb90b1a5d4bbe59c2eb8e3f3e108f49b98fd0    HEAD
DEBUG [baacc1b3]    9451025272b2a594ffc2af259bfce50c66ff15fc    refs/heads/dev
DEBUG [baacc1b3]    5cadb90b1a5d4bbe59c2eb8e3f3e108f49b98fd0    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [baacc1b3] Finished in 2.724 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

When I deploy using the following code bundle exec cap dev deploy ( http://pastebin.com/fCWRjEyv ), capistrano fails at

```
DEBUG [e6f95da6] Command: cd /home/parisstilton/dev.theparisstilton.com/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git checkout -B 20140806215353 origin/dev )
DEBUG [e6f95da6]    error: unknown switch `B'
DEBUG [e6f95da6]    usage: git checkout [options] <branch>
DEBUG [e6f95da6]       or: git checkout [options] [<branch>] -- <file>...
```

However if I ssh into the dreamhost server and run the same command it works fine recognising the git checkout -B flag. I suspect that this may be because I have installed a more recent version of git (2.0.4) in my ~/packages/bin/ which is in my $PATH. Where as the default git on Dreamhost is git version 1.7.2.5.

```
[beehive]$ cd /home/parisstilton/dev.theparisstilton.com/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/parisstilton/tmp/theparisstilton.com/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git checkout -B 20140806215353 origin/dev )
    Branch 20140806215353 set up to track remote branch dev from origin.
    Switched to a new branch '20140806215353'
```

Comment: SSH to Dreamhost and do `$ which git` and paste your result here please.

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279705/using-capistrano-when-remote-git-is-on-a-non-standard-path

Comment: @cfx thanks so much for the speedy reply!

which git
/home/parisstilton/packages/bin/git

echo $PATH
/home/parisstilton/packages/bin:/home/parisstilton/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games

I've tried adjusting my deploy.rb to some of the suggestions in that link. Adding, set :scm_command, "/home/parisstilton/packages/bin/git"

set :local_scm_command, "/usr/bin/git"

and trying set :deploy_via, :copy

But again cap fails on the same error: error: unknown switch `B'

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1993985/1231001 and make `/home/parisstilton/packages/bin/git` the first path

Comment: @cfx thank you so much for your help and perserverance. 

I tried the examples outlined in the suggested post but again still kept getting either the same git checukout -B error. I'd searched online and found that potentially this was a syntax from Capistrano 2. So tried this instead...

set :default_env {'PATH' => 'PATH=/home/theparisstilton/packages/bin/git:$PATH'}

But gave the following errors:
config/deploy.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input

I actually found a solution outlined below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a simple solution (though not sure if it's right, it works for me).

Editing the ~/.bashrc file to update $PATH as this is run by non-interactive shells where as ~/.bash_profile where I had originally updated my $PATH, is only run by bash on interactive shell login.

So here's the code.

```
$nano ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
#add ~/packages/bin installed apps/git to $PATH
export PATH=~/packages/bin:$PATH
```